# number of units in the output layer of Hierarchical Softmax

Tags: neural-network, word2vec, hierarchical, softmax

In word2vec, there are 3 layers: input, hidden, and output layer.

If we use the traditional softmax approach,
for a corpus with size V, the number of units of the output layer will be also V (one-hot vector input).

If we use Hierarchical Softmax,
the article says that there are only V-1 nodes (in the Huffman binary tree).
Does it mean there are only V-1 units in the output layer in the case?

Here is the reference I am reading:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.2738.pdf

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

In practice, word2vec hierarchical-softmax implementations create an output layer with exactly as many nodes as vocabulary words. See for example in the original Google word2vec.c line:

https://github.com/tmikolov/word2vec/blob/20c129af10659f7c50e86e3be406df663beff438/word2vec.c#L356

Or in the gensim Python implementation line:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/f3bf792ee1344ed17ad2836ab3c38b4210f59889/gensim/models/word2vec.py#L1171

You can then see how words are assigned individual Huffman codes and nodes ('points`) in the output layer in the [CreateBinaryTree](https://github.com/tmikolov/word2vec/blob/20c129af10659f7c50e86e3be406df663beff438/word2vec.c#L207) (C) or [create_binary_tree](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/f3bf792ee1344ed17ad2836ab3c38b4210f59889/gensim/models/word2vec.py#L539) functions.

Comment: but in the page [CreateBinaryTree](https://github.com/tmikolov/word2vec/blob/20c129af10659f7c50e86e3be406df663beff438/word2vec.c#L218), number of nodes = V- 1, which is not the same as the number of vocabulary words?

Comment: Ah, yes, you're right. So both the original word2vec.c and gensim's implementation allocate a full length-of-vocabulary array for the HS output weights... but don't use the last slot. So, it seems the answer to your question may be, "yes, there are V-1 active nodes, but one more is allocated and unused". You might want to try changing the existing code to allocate one less, and see if anything breaks, to confirm this interpretation.

Comment: I agree with you. Thank you for your great help! :P